# MVVM Treeview selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

Есть проект MVVM WPF, в проекте есть несколько моделей данных с иерархической структурой (Проект -> здания -> комплекты -> документы). Всё это помещается в TreeView (до этого момнета всё работает).

Далее задача чтобы по клику на людой элемент TreeView отображались данные от этом элементе.
Проблема в том, что при нажатии на элемент ничего не отображается ни в TextBlock который находится в StackPanel, а в TextBlock который должен отображать состояние свойства IsSelected всегда отображается False. Хотя при отладке всё хорошо, но как только процесс завершается и возвращается доступ к программе, всё пусто

Тут привожу две модели данных (есть ещё), ViewMode и View

```
{
internal class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    string? project_number;

    public string? Project_number
    {
        get { return project_number; }
        set
        {
            project_number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("project_number");
        }
    }

    string? project_name;

    public string? Project_name
    {
        get { return project_name; }
        set
        {
            project_name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("project_name");
        }
    }

    string? project_excutor;

    public string? Project_excutor
    {
        get { return project_excutor; }
        set
        {
            project_excutor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("project_excutor");
        }
    }

    string? project_date;

    public string? Project_date
    {
        get { return project_date; }
        set
        {
            project_excutor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("project_date");
        }
    }

    string? project_change_date;

    public string? Project_change_date
    {
        get { return project_change_date; }
        set
        {
            project_change_date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("project_date");
        }
    }



    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Building> Object_list { get; set; } 
    public Project()
    {
        Object_list = new ObservableCollection<Building>();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

}

```
{
internal class Building : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    string? object_cod;

    public string? Object_cod
    {
        get { return object_cod; }
        set
        {
            object_cod = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("object_cod");
        }
    }

    string? object_name;

    public string? Object_name
    {
        get { return object_name; }
        set
        {
            object_name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("object_name");
        }
    }

    string? object_executor;

    public string? Object_executor
    {
        get { return object_cod; }
        set
        {
            object_cod = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("object_executor");
        }
    }



    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    public Project? Project { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public List<Complect> Complect_list { get; set; } = new List<Complect>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

}
```

}

```
{
internal class AppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Project> project_list;
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Project_list
    {
        get { return project_list; }
        set
        {
            project_list = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("project_list");
        }
    }



    private Building itemBuilding;
    public Building ItemBuilding
    {
        get { return itemBuilding; }
        set
        {
            //OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            if (SelectedItem.GetType() == typeof(Building))
            {
                itemBuilding = (Building)SelectedItem;
            }
        }
    }


    private object selectedItem;

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            //OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            if (IsSelected == true)
            {
                SelectedItem = this;
                var tmp = SelectedItem;
            }
        }
    }





    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }



    private RelayCommand run;
    public RelayCommand Run3
    {
        get
        {
            return run ??
              (run = new RelayCommand(obj =>
              {
                  Program prog = new Program();
                  prog.Run();
              }));
        }
    }
    public AppViewModel()
    {
        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            Project prj1 = new Project { Project_number = "12-123-65", Project_name = "prj111" };
            Project prj2 = new Project { Project_number = "12-456-98", Project_name = "prj222" };
            Building obj1 = new Building { Project = prj1, Object_cod = "01", Object_name = "House1" };
            Building obj2 = new Building { Project = prj1, Object_cod = "02", Object_name = "House2" };
            Building obj3 = new Building { Project = prj2, Object_cod = "01", Object_name = "House1" };
            Building obj4 = new Building { Project = prj2, Object_cod = "02", Object_name = "House2" };
            Complect IOS1 = new Complect { Building = obj2, Mark = "ИОС1" };
            Complect IOS5 = new Complect { Building = obj1, Mark = "ИОС5" };
            Document draw = new Document { Complect = IOS1, Name = "План" };
            Document spec = new Document { Complect = IOS1, Name = "Спецификация" };


            Catalog executors = new Catalog { catalog_name = "executors" };
            Write ivanov = new Write { Name = "Ivanov", Catalog = executors };
            Write petrov = new Write { Name = "Petrov", Catalog = executors };


            db.Projects.AddRange(prj1, prj2);
            db.Buildings.AddRange(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4);
            db.Complects.AddRange(IOS1, IOS5);
            db.Documents.AddRange(draw, spec);
            db.Catalogs.Add(executors);
            db.Writes.AddRange(ivanov, petrov);
            db.SaveChanges();



            project_list = db.Projects.Local.ToObservableCollection();

        }

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; //реализация интерфейса
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

}

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1" xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.MVVM" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=mvvm:AppViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="794">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView
        Grid.Column="0"
        Name="TreeView_PRJ" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Project_list}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="documentTemplate" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="complectTemplate" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Document_list}" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=documentTemplate}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Mark}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="buildingTemplate" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Complect_list}" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=complectTemplate}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Object_name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Object_list}" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=buildingTemplate}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Project_name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <StackPanel 
        Grid.Column="1"
        x:Name="_1" DataContext="{Binding ItemBuilding}" Height="93" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="16,55,16,0" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Object_name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Margin="177,326,126,88" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}" Width="50" Height="20" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. не хватает репутации не могу комментировать.
Первое что я заметил - это не правильный вызов `OnPropertyChanged`. У вас в методе стоит замечательная `CallerMemberName` которая позволяет "отпускать" вызов по типу `OnPropertyChanged("имя переменной")`, поэтому вы можете убрать везде свои `OnPropertyChanged("object_cod")` на простое `OnPropertyChanged()`.
Второе - при вызове `OnPropertyChanged` в параметры нужно кидать публичное свойство, т.е. не  `OnPropertyChanged("object_cod")`, а `OnPropertyChanged("Object_cod")` т.к. **XAML** куда вы биндите, не может обращаться к приватным переменным.
Третье - я заметил, что вы не вызываете `OnPropertyChanged` на ваш **SelectedItem**, хотя возможно это сделано намерено.
Попробуйте для начала это, а дальше попробуем разобраться.
Еще я бы вам рекомендовал сделать что-то типа **BaseClass**, который наследует **INotifyPropertyChanged** и наследовать все ваши **ViewModel** от этого **BaseClass** дабы не писать в каждой **ViewModel** реализацию этого интерфейса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ) Почему то удалился предыдущий ответ и комментарии к нему. Собственно код уже поменял, в SelectedItem добавил OnPropertyChanged. Проблема не ушла. Более того, я в главное окно вывожу состояние свойства IsSelected из VM и оно всегда остаётся False, хотя при отладке (точка остонава на IsSelected модели) и свойство IsSelected модели и VM становяться True.

Comment: @Denton Если есть возможность на гитхабе например выложить, я бы посмотрел. Так чет не вижу в чем может быть проблема. Единственное что еще заметил для меня не совсем понятное - в AppViewModel для IsSelected у вас нет никакой логики как должно обновиться в случае true - SelectedItem или ItemBuilding к которому вы биндитесь во второй колонке. Так же вам нужно понимать, что свойство IsSelected биндится для TreeViewItem, а он у вас типа Project, а во второй колонке вы обращаетесь к IsSelected объекта AppViewModel

Comment: https://github.com/DCCCDenton/Test_Solution_EF/tree/VM/WpfApp1

Comment: @Denton ссылка сломана

Comment: Поправил, сейчас должно открыться

Comment: @Denton Добрались руки. Смотрите, вы биндитесь к коллекции  Project_list. В классе Project у вас не хватает свойства IsSelected которое вам и нужно. Об этом даже пишет Xaml binding error. Второе. Если вы хотите в вашей AppViewModel получать информацию какой Project сейчас выбран то пути 2. Первый это сделать эвент в Project и при добавлении в коллекцию Project_list подписываться на создание нового элемента Project. В самом классе - в свойстве IsSelected на set методе вызывать эвент. Второй вариант - сделать attached property на эвент SelectedItemChanged и команду в AppViewModel

Comment: @Denton команда бы вызывалась в любой момент когда вызывается SelectedItemChanged у TreeView, таким образом из EventArgs можно было бы понять какой элемент кликнут. Второй вариант не совсем крут для инкапсуляции может быть, но вам не так важно. Первый же вариант немного сложный если вы не знакомы с эвентами т.к. кода придется побольше пописать и логику отписывания (если удалять элемент), но все это довольно просто на самом деле т.к. у коллекции типа ObservableCollection уже есть эвент который слушает разные типы эвентов которые у нее вызываются (add/delete/remove и тд)

Comment: огромное спасибо буду пробовать )))